# Place before content outside the anchor tag using CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have used `:before` and added some content using CSS `content` property before anchor tags.
I want to place this content above the anchor tags but facing some issues in positioning when padding is applied on anchor tags. Please check the jsbin demo to make things clear.

### [Check at JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ebafec/6/edit)

Here is my CSS code

```
ul {
  margin-top:200px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  height: 100px;
}

a {
  outline: 4px solid skyblue;
}

a:before {
  content: "top place";
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  
  /* To move it to top of anchor element*/
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

.b {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

Comment: You can just remove the `padding: 40px;` in `b` class and you get it outside. Is that what you want?

Comment: Removing padding is not a good solution as It would mess up the page layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want the `::before` pseudo-element to sit on the top border, flush to the left side, I'd suggest:

```
a {
    outline: 4px solid skyblue;
    position: relative;
}

a:before {
    /* Everything else as before, unchanged */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: -4px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q88XJ/1/).

Comment: I want to place before content only when user presses a button as per my UI. I doubt if doing position:relative on anchor tags can mess the layout of page. It possibly can. Is there any way, I can just drag the before content outside without touching properties of A ?

Comment: And when user presses it again, before content goes away. I have successfully implemented it. I am just unable to place this before content properly on border.

Comment: Can you explain, step-by-step, what the user should do and what should happen? This *may* be possible with HTML/CSS, but it *might* require JavaScript; but I'm not sure, yet, quite what you're wanting.

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong with David's solution or mine. Setting `position: relative` does not necessarily change the page layout. I don't think there is another way of solving this, beside using an unnecessary amount of JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas There is a button on a page using which user can highlight all the anchor tags So suppose in my page, there is an anchor tag which is absolutely positioned already and now user clicks on the button we set relative position on anchor tag which will override the exising absolute property. So it is just my doubt it can possibly mess up with things. Am I clear ?

Comment: It might, the only reason I used `position: relative` is to force the descendant pseudo-element to be positioned relative to that element, not the page itself. In this case case, though, you'd be able to use `position: absolute` instead (as you could with any `position` other than (the default) `static`).

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this? [**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/ivivik/6/edit)

Absolute positioning is done with using `top, left, right and bottom` not `margin`

```
a {
    position: relative;
    outline: 4px solid skyblue;
}

a:before {
    ...

    /* To move it to top of anchor element*/
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: -4px;
}
```

Add `position: relative` to `a`, because it's the parent element of `a:before` and the `absolute` position of `a:before` will be relative to `a`